# Why most military transport aircrafts use turboprop engines?

Tags: aircraft-design, military

What is the reason behind that most (or many) military transport aircraft use turboprop engines?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the main purpose of the mission.
For example, for long haul flights, carring many pallets, they will use probably the turbo jets, because they have more endurance, and normally they will land on longer runways.

Comment: You may provide some contexte and links, and develop you answer. See [this help page](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: Also, you can edit your previous answer to include more information instead of creating a new, nearly equally short, one.